# Compare 2 interfaces

Tags: .net, oop, operators, operator-overloading

```
interface I //: IEquatable<I>
{ }

class A : I
{
    static public bool operator !=(A a, I i)
    {
        return !(a == i);
    }

    static public bool operator ==(A a, I i)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is I)
            return this == (I)obj;
        else
            return base.Equals(obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }
}

class B : I
{
    static public bool operator !=(B b, I i)
    {
        return !(b == i);
    }

    static public bool operator ==(B b, I i)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is I)
            return this == (I)obj;
        else
            return base.Equals(obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }
}
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<I> iss = new List<I>();
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        iss.Add(a);
        iss.Add(b);

        if (iss[0] == iss[1])
            Console.WriteLine("a == b");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("a != b");

        if (iss[1] == iss[0])
            Console.WriteLine("b == a");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("b != a");
    }
}
```

The output is

```
a != b
b != a
```

I expected

```
a == b
b != a
```

Could somebody can explain it?

Answer (score 1):

I'd set a breakpoint in each class's Equals() method and == operator, and see what gets called to evaluate each expression. It's obviously not what you expect. My guess is that because `I` does not and cannot require implementors to expose a `==` operator, when two `I`s are compared as you're doing, the runtime doesn't bother looking for overloaded operators and instead resorts to the System.Object `==`, which performs a referential check.

Comment: interfaces can't have operators... but what if I *need* to force compare two I's?

Comment: Require implementers of I to expose a named method like "SemanticallyEquals(I other)". Then, whether you treat the objects as Is or As and Bs, this method is available at that inheritance level (and not Object) so the call is guaranteed to follow your inheritance hierarchy instead of finding a shortcut.

Comment: Why not just have the interface extend `IEquatable<I>`?

Comment: @Mark Sowul: As you can see, your proposal was commented in my code... does not work, you can test it. I need A==I be true, B==I - false.

Comment: My comment was in response to Keith's recommendation of SemanticallyEquals. You shouldn't be using == for this because you seek semantic equality, not reference equality. See here [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer:

You have a `List<I>` and you compare two `I` with each other. Because `interface I` does not (and cannot) implement a compare operator the objects are compared by reference.

Instead you could use an abstract base class:

```
public interface I
{
}

public abstract class AbstractI : I
{
    public static bool operator ==(AbstractI left, I right)
    {
        return left.equals(right); //TODO can be null
    }
    public static bool operator !=(AbstractI left, I right)
    {
        return !left.equals(right);
    }

    protected abstract bool equals(I other);
}

public class A : AbstractI
{
    protected override bool equals(I other)
    {
        //TODO your compare code here
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class B : AbstractI
{
    protected override bool equals(I other)
    {
        //TODO your compare code here
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}


List<AbstractI> l = new List<AbstractI>(){
    new A(),
    new B()
};

var x = l[0] == l[1];
```

Comment: interfaces can't have operators... but what if I need to compare two I's?

Comment: If you are trying to compare if two objects implement the same interface try using the is key work.  You should be able to do something like if(A is I && B is I). Not quite sure if that's what you are looking for though.

Comment: You would probabply end up with a static compare method or an abstract base class instead of an interface.

Comment: @cptScarlet: no, this is not about `Is`, nor about testing the interface implementation. Is about comparing 2 objects, not their types.

Comment: @matthias.lukaszek: So, how to "attach" this static method to standard object comparation (using ==)?

Comment: As far as I know you can't attach such a static method as operator.

Comment: don't like it. My A and B classes **implements** same interfaces, but **inherits** two different classes. PS Remark: Microsoft uses Uppercase names for all kind of functions )

Comment: I guess in that case you have to use a method to compare the interfaces.